# How do I insert data to a database without clicking the insert button

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 C#

I have a FormView in Insert mode, linked to an MSSQL database, with 2 hidden fields in it.

These fields are populated when the page loads.

I now need this data to be inputted to the database automatically without anyone having to click on an insert button.

How do I achieve this once the data has bound?

Here is the code I have been trying, it's working except the adnumber value is not uploading, only the date

```
      protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ad, insertqry;
    ad = ((HiddenField)(FormView1.FindControl("Adnumber"))).Value;
   DateTime hit = DateTime.Now;

    insertqry = "insert AdvertsHits(ad,hit) values(@ad,@hit)";

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertqry, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ad", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = ad;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@hit", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = hit;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Please have a look now at what I have tried, the date is making it to the database but no the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to insert data into data base and call that method after hidden fields get the data, then data automatically inserted into database.

Comment: That makes sense, how to do that is "above my pay grade" :-) But you have pointed me in a direction, thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at the new code I posted, It works except that only the datetime goes into the database, not the VarChar, can you see any glaring mistake I have made.  I have been trying for a day now to fix it.

Comment: in the above code is value coming to variable ad, did you checked this, other wise take a break point and check it, if value not comes to the variable ad then change the try in another process to get it,